# Could not connect to database using mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack, mlab

I have developed mean stack application. I am trying to connect to database using mongolab but i could not .I am providing the code down below , Please tell me where i have gone wrong .Thanks in advance

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://tgif:tgifpass@ds137256.mlab.com:37256/contacts', function(err,database){
if(err)
    return console.log("error connecting to database");
else
{
var db = database;
console.log("connected to " + db);
}

});

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: **Be careful not to share your database crendentials and your database URL !** This is critical information, you should consider replacing thiem by fake information...

Comment: DB Credentials are fake  only bro :P

Comment: Alright then. What is the state of your database in MongoLab ?